# how to use django-registeration in django framework?

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I know my question my be simple or basic. But i am asking this because i searched a good article or tutorial so much and didn't find any good detailed article related to `django-registration`. can any one help me to explain or to give example that how to use this.

Note: Please don't mark negatively if you don't like my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't already, you should read the [django-registration docs](https://django-registration.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html). The [quick start guide](https://django-registration.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html) looks particularly useful.

A quick google also returned a few blog post including [django registration for newbies](http://www.stonemind.net/blog/2007/04/13/django-registration-for-newbies/) and [setting up django registration](http://www.michelepasin.org/blog/2011/01/14/setting-up-django-registration/).

If you get stuck further down the line, I suggest you check through some of the [more popular django-registration questions already anwsered on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-registration?sort=votes&pageSize=15), or even the [source code](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/8f242e35ef7c004e035e54b4bb093c32bf77c29f/registration/?at=default) if you are feeling adventurous.